# So where is this calling super?

Tags: iphone, core-data

From [the Core Data docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW1):

> Inheritance If you have two subclasses
>   of NSManagedObject where the parent
>   class implements a dynamic property
>   and its subclass (the grandchild of
>   NSManagedObject) overrides the methods
>   for the property, those overrides
>   cannot call super.

```
@interface Parent : NSManagedObject
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* parentString;
@end

@implementation Parent
@dynamic parentString;
@end

@interface Child : Parent
@end

@implementation Child
- (NSString *)parentString
{
    // this throws a "selector not found" exception
    return parentString.foo;
}
@end
```

very, very funny, because: I see nobody calling super. Or are they? Wait... parentString.foo results in ... a crash ??? it's a string. How can that thing have a .foo suffixed to it? Just another documentation bug?

Comment: I marked this for document feedback at Apple. You should do so as well.

Comment: how and where? would love to do so, if it wouldn't take the whole day to find the right contact person ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the example is garbled.

I pretty sure the inheritance issue is caused because @dynamic methods are created by the runtime. The complier does not attempt to create a symbol for them. If the parent class isn't instantiated, I don't think the methods even exist at all. Therefore, its really impossible for a subclass instance to have a live selector/symbol to call.

It's a tradeoff necessary for automatic runtime code generation.